# the operator-> return value of smart pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

smart pointers like shared_ptr can be used like ordinary pointers with `*` and `->` operator.
The books say that `->` operator returns the pointer that shared_ptr stores. So you can use it to access the object this pointer points to. But I am confused here. Look at the code below.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int v = 20){val = v;}
    int val;
}
A* p1 = new A;
std::cout<<p1->val;  //This is common sense

boost::shared_ptr<A> p2(new A);
std::cout<<p2->val;  //This is right
//My question is that p2-> returns the pointers of the object, then maybe another 
//-> should be used?
//like (p2->)->val?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's magic. Well, more like a special case. The standard says that

> **13.5.6 Class member access [over.ref]**
>
> 1 `operator->` shall be a non-static member function taking no parameters. It implements the class member access syntax that uses `->`.
>
> postﬁx-expression -> templateopt id-expression
> postﬁx-expression -> pseudo-destructor-name
>
> **An expression `x->m`is interpreted as `(x.operator->())->m`** for a class object `x` of type `T` if `T::operator->()`
> exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism (13.3).

That is, `operator->` is called again on the result of the overloaded operator. And if that one is overloaded too, it goes on recursively until a raw pointer is the result and the built-in `operator->` is called.

That doesn't mean the result can't be any arbitrary type - it can be, but then you can only call it with the function call syntax:

```
struct X {
    int operator->() { return 42; }
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    x.operator->(); // this is OK
}
```

Comment: Similar explanation is here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access

_If a user-defined `operator->` is provided, the `operator->` is called again on the value that it returns, **recursively**, until an `operator->` is reached that returns a **plain pointer**. After that, built-in semantics are applied to that pointer._

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, designers of C++ realized this, and changed the semantics of the overloaded infix `->` operator to mean that the pointer returned by your operator is plugged in on the left-hand side of the `->` operator, and then the member is accessed as usual.

If you were to invoke the `->` operator explicitly, you would need to insert an additional `->`, though:

```
std::cout << p1.operator->()->val;
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/ubI4uv).

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `operator ->` is not the same as what `p2->val` returns. The return value of `operator ->` is a pointer that will be used to access the `val` member, so `p2->val` works as expected.