# Result of ‘operator->()’ yields non-pointer result

Tags: c++, c++11

In this code:

```
while(k != listeners.getLength()) {
    if(listeners[k] != nullptr) {
        listeners[k]->onNewMessage(*newMessage);
    }
    k++;
}
```

The compiler does not like the `->` at all.

`listeners[k]` is a class with an `operator->()` that is both public and defined, returning a reference to a type with a (virtual) method `onNewMessage`.

Changing it to:

```
while(k != listeners.getLength()) {
    if(listeners[k] != nullptr) {
        listeners[k].operator ->().onNewMessage(*newMessage);
    }
    k++;
}
```

works.

It **used** to work. I added some boolean operators (`==` and `!=` to the type returned by reference of `listeners[k]`). I also added a constructor for a `::std::nullptr_t` type. I can't see any reason why these would cause a problem, and the error mentions no ambiguity so it's not that it has too many options.

Why is there a problem here?

**Addendum**

To clarify the structure is as follows:

```
List<PtrWrapper<LogListener>> listeners;
```

`T& List<T>::operator[](int);` and a const definition to go with it.

`T& PtrWrapper<T>::operator->();` and a const version to go with it.

`LogListener` has a virtual method `onNewMessage`.

So `listeners[k]` is a `PtrWrapper<LogListener>&`.

Comment: Can you post the definition of this `operator->()`? If it's returning a reference, shouldn't you be using `listeners[k].onNewMessage(...)`?

Comment: If you're going to use it in a postfix expression, it needs to return a pointer type. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583450/the-operator-return-value-of-smart-pointers/20583499#20583499).

Comment: "Yields non-pointer result" your second example has `.onNewMessage` so that one doesn't yield a pointer result either.  What is the compiler error message? And what's the function prototype for your `operator->`?

Comment: @Praetorian added, I've not given function bodies because they're not relevant and that'd be a lot of code.

Comment: @AlecTeal `T& PtrWrapper<T>::operator->()` should probably be `T* PtrWrapper<T>::operator->()`

Answer (score 25):

The `operator->()` is a bit of an odd-ball: although it can return a non-pointer type, the resulting type would need to overload the `operator->()`, too! Basically, when the compiler sees a use of an overloaded `operator->()` it will keep applying `operator->()`s until the result is a pointer. Once a pointer is obtained, it knows how to access the corresponding member.

It is an error if repeated application of `operator->()` leads to a non-pointer type which doesn't overload `operator->()`.

Answer (score 1):

I was being silly, while a more useful error would have been nice I buggered up overloading ->.

The best explanation of what C++ tries to do is Jrok's answer: [the operator-> return value of smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583450/the-operator-return-value-of-smart-pointers/20583499#20583499)

I simply returned `T*` rather than `T&` from `operator->` to fix.